# SQL Conditional Select from SharePoint

Tags: sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm creating a search page on our SharePoint site that will allow users to find results from a SQL table by either performing a search from a text box @Param1, **or** selecting a value from a dropdown @SiteParam.

My SQL SelectStatement is

```
SELECT * FROM [Routing] 
    WHERE [Site] LIKE 
        CASE WHEN @Param1 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN '%' + @Param1 + '%' 
            ELSE @SiteParam
```

This works great in SQL when I declare the parameters and set values for the search, but not so much in SharePoint.

I've been able to get it to work if I don't do the case and just use 1 of the parameters, but I haven't found a way to get it to do either of them.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I haven't had to set up expressions in SharePoint, but I have written them for SSRS reports. I am pretty sure you will have to write the expression in Visual Basic. Because of this, you can't use `CASE...WHEN...THEN` conditional syntax - you will likely need to use `IIF()`. [Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: How are you calling this query?  In a custom web part?

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply - been overwhelmed with other projects. Getting back to this though, I'm calling it as a ASP SQL Data Source